# order_by intermediate table for given relation in SQL with Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

```
class Nutrient(models.Model):
    tagname = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class FoodNutrientAmount(models.Model):
    nutrient = models.ForeignKey(Nutrient)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food)
    amount = models.FloatField()


class Food(models.Model):
    nutrients = models.ManyToManyField(
        Nutrient,
        through=FoodNutrientAmount,
    )
```

So, I can get the Foods ordered by the amount of `tagname=FOL` Nutrient with a list comprehension:

```
ordered_fnas = FoodNutrientAmount.objects.filter(
    nutrient__tagname="FOL"
).order_by('-amount')
ordered_foods_by_most_fol = [fna.food for fna in ordered_fnas]
```

Can I get such an iterable as a queryset without taking the whole thing into memory?

Maybe there is a different approach using `Food.objects.annotate` or `extra`? I can't think of a great way to do it at the moment.

I can get close with values_list; but, I get the ordered list of pks and not the queryset of `Food` objects that I want.

```
FoodNutrientAmount.objects.filter(
    nutrient__tagname='FOL'
).order_by('-amount').v‌​alues_list('food', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

This is a Many-to-many relationship. So you can probably leverage that. How about adding default ordering to `FoodNutrientAmount` and then you can just do normal manytomany queries.

```
class FoodNutrientAmount(models.Model):
    nutrient = models.ForeignKey(Nutrient)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food)
    amount = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-amount',)
```

Then you can just call -

```
nutritious_foods = Food.objects.filter(nutrients__tagname='FOL').order_by('foodnutrientamount')
```

Comment: I want an ordered iterable of `Food` objects. I know all about `values_list` and `flat=True` but it has nothing to do with the question, not so far, at least. `FoodNutrientAmount.objects.filter(nutrient__tagname='FOL').order_by('-amount').values_list('food', flat=True)` is close, that gives me the list of ids.

Comment: @SkylarSaveland yes, that's exactly what I wanted to write, forgot to edit the code when taking from documentation. Try putting `filter` first, then `values_list` and then `order`. This seems like the only way to get an iterable of attributes among a Model.

Comment: @SkylarSaveland Changed the asnwer. See if it helps.

Comment: unfortunately, no. The `Food` qs does not end up ordered; but, you are close to something, `Food.objects.filter(nutrients__tagname='FOL').order_by('foodnutrientamount')` remarkably, does order the foods by the FoodNutrientAmount -amount

Comment: add that `order_by` and you've got a deal.

Comment: `SELECT "nutrition_data_food"."id", ... FROM "nutrition_data_food" INNER JOIN "nutrition_data_foodnutrientamount" ON ("nutrition_data_food"."id" = "nutrition_data_foodnutrientamount"."food_id") INNER JOIN "nutrition_data_nutrient" ON ("nutrition_data_foodnutrientamount"."nutrient_id" = "nutrition_data_nutrient"."id") WHERE "nutrition_data_nutrient"."tagname" = FOL  ORDER BY "nutrition_data_foodnutrientamount"."amount" DESC`

Comment: @SkylarSaveland added the `order_by`.